# How do I get protoc onto Cloudbees Jenkins setup

Tags: jenkins, protocol-buffers, cloudbees

I'm pretty new to Cloudbees and Jenkins, and need to get a gradle build to have access to a compiled version of protoc from Google's protobuf project to generate some necessary Java code for a project.

My best guess offhand would be that I would have to add either a build with an output artifact to build it for the Jenkins server and pull it in with the other project... or add it as a build target for the dependent project... though that seems pretty messy. Is there a better/right way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was not too hard to add another Jenkins build, export the protoc binary as an artifact, and import the protoc artifact into the required build.

Build-step:

```
wget https://protobuf.googlecode.com/files/protobuf-2.5.0.tar.bz2
tar xjvf protobuf-2.5.0.tar.bz2
cd protobuf-2.5.0
./configure --disable-shared
make -j4
strip src/protoc
```

Leaving this as inspiration, though hopefully someone else comes up with a cleaner solution that I don't know have any clue exists.